# Interpreting Learning Curves

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm curious on how to interpret the following learning curves, which can be considered an actual good learning curve of the three learning curves. I'm not sure when to consider if there is a high variance or bias, likewise the presence of underfitting or overfitting respectively. Thank you in advanced.

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

3.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bias and variance and their effect on overfitting and underfitting summarized in one illustration

[image]

Therefore, I think you a fit model, with reasonable variance and bias.